# Can I set a timeout for copying files in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, data-recovery

I'm still learning ubuntu.  I'm attempting to pull some data from a HDD in Ubuntu 14.xx.  Currently it says I have 8,011 hours left to pull ~150GB via USB.  To speed this up, is there any way to set a timeout option with the copy function to allow it to skip corrupted files after a set length of time, forcing it to continue?  Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For copying data off a failing drive I highly recommend [ddrescue](http://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/ddrescue.html).

As [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/manual/ddrescue_manual.html) states you can rescue the most important part of the drive first:

```
ddrescue -i0 -s50MiB /dev/hdc hdimage logfile
ddrescue -i0 -s1MiB -d -r3 /dev/hdc hdimage logfile
```

Then rescue some key drive areas:

```
ddrescue -i30GiB -s10GiB /dev/hdc hdimage logfile
ddrescue -i230GiB -s5GiB /dev/hdc hdimage logfile
```

Finally rescue the rest (does not recopy what is already done):

```
ddrescue /dev/hdc hdimage logfile
ddrescue -d -r3 /dev/hdc hdimage logfile
```

You can add the `-T <interval>` or `--timeout=<interval>` option if you want.